# C# Windows Service - Timer is not working in debugging

Tags: c#, asp.net, service, timer, windows-services

I have started building up the windows service in the c# language. And i want to implement the timer feature inside it. But for some reason, the **DoIt** timer event handler is not getting fired during the debugging and i am not getting any exception also. I am trying to debug the windows service using Debug->Start new instance.

The line TraceLog.WriteTrace("Router Service Started"); does get hit and executed.

```
   public partial class EntryPoint : ServiceBase
    {
        private const int TIMER_INTERVAL = 10000;
        private System.Timers.Timer mvTimer = new System.Timers.Timer();

        [MTAThread()]
        [System.Diagnostics.DebuggerNonUserCode()]
        public static void Main()
        {
            #if DEBUG
                        EntryPoint service = new EntryPoint();
                        service.Start();
            #else
                        ServiceBase[] ServicesToRun;
                        ServicesToRun = new ServiceBase[] 
                        { 
                            new EntryPoint() 
                        };
                        ServiceBase.Run(ServicesToRun);
            #endif
        }
        public EntryPoint()
        {
            AppDomain.CurrentDomain.UnhandledException += new UnhandledExceptionEventHandler(CurrentDomain_UnhandledException);
            InitializeComponent();
        }

        private void CurrentDomain_UnhandledException(object sender, UnhandledExceptionEventArgs e)
        {
            Exception ex = (Exception)e.ExceptionObject;
            if (ex != null)
            {
                Console.WriteLine(ex);
            }
        }


        public void Start()
        {
            OnStart(null);
        }

        protected override void OnStart(string[] args)
        {
            TraceLog.SetTrace(ConfigurationManager.AppSettings["RouterTraceLog"]);
            TraceLog.WriteTrace("Router Service Started");

            mvTimer = new Timer();
            mvTimer.Elapsed += new ElapsedEventHandler(DoIt);
            try
            {
                mvTimer.Interval = TIMER_INTERVAL;
                mvTimer.Enabled = true;                
            }
            catch (Exception ex)
            {
                mvTimer.Interval = TIMER_INTERVAL;
                TraceLog.WriteTrace(ex.Message);
            }
        }

        private void DoIt(object sender, ElapsedEventArgs e)
        {
            TraceLog.WriteTrace("Inside DoIt :: " + DateTime.UtcNow.ToString());
        }

        protected override void OnStop()
        {
            mvTimer.Enabled = false;
            TraceLog.WriteTrace("Router Service stopping");
        }
```

[image]

Please suggest. I am missing something very small and not able to nail it down.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In debug mode, the application exits after the function `OnStart` finishes. There's nothing to stop the application from quitting.

What you need is add a `Console.ReadLine();` to prevent the application from exiting.

```
#if DEBUG
      EntryPoint service = new EntryPoint();
      service.Start();
      Console.ReadLine();
#else
```

You can read more at [MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/7a50syb3(v=vs.110).aspx) on How to: Debug Windows Service Applications

Comment: I tried, but find no difference in using the ReadLine(). It is still doing the exit.

Comment: is the  Output type set to Console Application? there's no reason it will exit

Comment: Yes, it worked :-)  after i changed the output type to Console App. Thanks a ton mate :-)